# Refused to display "Link" in a frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to rotate couple of iFrames on one HTML site.
sites are accesable from same domain but not from outside.

getting error in browser console

> Refused to display 'local-domain-link' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

i am a beginner in Programing/coding/etc and at Stack.

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask. Are you saying that you are getting the error despite not having ancestors from different origins? Are you asking how to change the configuration to allow ancestors from different origins? Are you asking how to override a third-parties security policy and display their content in a frame from a different origin against their wishes?

Comment: Set `SAMEORIGIN` header then only it will load resources from cross origin.

Comment: @SumeshTG — The question is asking about CSP not X-Frame-Options. (CSP is a replacement for X-Frame-Options that is much more flexible and coverts content other than frames too).

Comment: sure, here is my code:
var links = [
  "http://bf-se-jira.befine.local/login.jsp",
  "https://example-local/",
  "https://example-local/"
];

var bigFrame = document.getElementById("bigFrame");
var sideTopFrame = document.getElementById("sideTopFrame");
var sideBotFrame = document.getElementById("sideBotFrame");

setInterval(60000)
function getLinks(){
bigFrame.src=links[0];
sideTopFrame.src=links[1];
sideBotFrame.src=links[2];
var fL = links.shift();
links.push(fL);
};

getLinks()
setInterval(getLinks,600000)